# I'm having some trouble with Kivy's ListView

Tags: python, kivy

So I've been having a little trouble with ListView. What I have been trying to do is make an API call to ebay. Then I setup a ListView with the results. However, here's the issue. The first time I do a search and it brings me to the results page, it only shows one result. If I scroll way down I will see another result or two pop up, but they disappear right away. Then I will go back to the main page and do the exact same search, however, this time when it goes to the results page, it lists a lot more content. If I scroll down everything seems fine at first, but then the spacing will mess up, there will be a huge gap of nothingness, then the results will be closer together. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOw9L.jpg) are a few pictures to better explain the issue (sorry I threw the code together real quick to test it.. been trying forever to fix this issue though)

kv file

```
#: import ListItemLabel kivy.uix.listview.ListItemLabel
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#: import CompositeListItem kivy.uix.listview.CompositeListItem
#: import AsyncImage kivy.uix.image.AsyncImage
#: import SelectableView kivy.uix.listview.SelectableView
#: import BoxLayout kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout
#: import main main

ScreenManagement:

<ScreenManagement>:
    SearchForm
    ResultPage



<SearchForm>:
    name: "search_screen"
    search_box:search_box
    search_button:search_button
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: "FLEA MARKET FLIP"
            font_size: 45
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":1}
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '100dp'
            TextInput:
                id: search_box
                text: ""
                size_hint_x: 0.5
                pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}
            Button:
                text: "Price It!"
                id:search_button
                on_release:
                root.manager.get_screen("result_page").results_list.adapter.data.clear()
                root.manager.get_screen("result_page").results_list.adapter.data.extend([s for s in app.root.ebay(search_box.text)])
                root.manager.get_screen("result_page").do_layout()
                root.manager.get_screen("result_page").results_list._trigger_reset_populate()
                app.root.current = "result_page"




<ResultPage>:
    name: "result_page"
    orientation: 'vertical'
    results_list:results_list
    ListView:
        padding:(100,110)
        id: results_list
        adapter: ListAdapter(data=[], cls=main.Ebay_Item, args_converter=root.args_converter, allow_empty_selection=False)
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint: [0.2,0.1]
            spacing: 50
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "y":0}
            text: "Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "search_screen"



<Ebay_Item>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    cols: 3
    #spacing: 60
    row_force_default: True
    row_default_height: 40
    Label:
        text: root.results[0]
        size: self.texture_size
        text_size: self.width, self.height
    Label:
        text: root.results[1]
        size: self.texture_size
    AsyncImage:
        allow_stretch: True
        size_hint_y: None
        size_hint_x: None
        source: root.results[2]
        size: self.texture_size
```

main.py

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from scripts.ebay import ebay_search
from kivy.uix.listview import SelectableView
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.app import App


class PriceItApp(App):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def ebay(self, data):
        return ebay_search(data)


class SearchForm(Screen):
    pass


class ResultPage(Screen):
    def args_converter(self, index, data_item):
        title, price, picture = data_item
        return {"results": [title, price, picture]}


class Ebay_Item(SelectableView, GridLayout):
    results = ListProperty()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PriceItApp().run()
```